# Remove XML component instead of hiding?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've got a layout which displays my date and then some code in a LinearLayout like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="wefwefwef"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:id="@+id/orange_message"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, what I want to do in my Java is to hide the TextView message_date.  I am currently doing this  using `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

This works, but it seems to keep the styling on message_date so orange_message actually appears further down the view. 
Is there anyway I can set it so that it acts as is message_date was never there?

Comment: I don't understand that when you use **setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)** everythings okey,I mean _TextView_ is gone. Then further that _TextView_ appears again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [View.GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

```
setVisibility(View.GONE)
```